# Complex data modeling with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, data-modeling

I'm new to NodeJS/Express and I'm watching a lot of video tutorials and reading articles but there is something that really annoys me:

I don't have a clue how to model a real world application. I mean, okay it's easy to create a document for a single object, ie: Users

But, what happens if you want to model a real application? Like creating relationships one2one, many2one, many2many... How do you address this problem when you are coding your apps?

Anyone knows any resource to learn to do this?? seems like all tutorials are so simple..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a real programming question and too broad.

Comment: You could try the mongodb university: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about

Answer (score 0):

It works same as in other systems too. I would first have a look at object orientation (if you haven't already) and then look into different database concepts.

You have at least 2 different layers for data modeling, one for persistence (database, saving the data, not much related to node.js) and one layer for working with the data within the application, in this layer you need to learn how to use OOP in JS / Node.js.

Then there might be additional layers depending on your application e.g. for view and data-transport. but i'd first recommend to look into the first 2 layers, database and oop. and as i said its not really so much related to node.js, these basic concepts would work quite similar in php, java and so on..